# can i find out the orignial value of a control with ViewState

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

In my ASP.NET web form, say I have something like this:

`<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="abc"></asp:Literal>`

Now say I change the text in the code behind. The control has viewstate enabled and so the new text value persists throughout postbacks which is exactly what I want. But in some scenarios I want to reset the control back to the original value (i.e. "abc") without having to hardcode it in the code behind. So without disabling viewstate, is there any way I can retrieve the original value that the control had when the screen was first loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Two controls. One hidden which contains the original value and never changes - Thats if you don't want to do it in your codebehind. You can also set up a variable in your code behind which holds the orignal value, or use sessions... there are tons of ways. pick and choose.

Comment: I have actually used a variation on this in the past which is to add an attribute called something like x_originalValue to the control. you get compilation warnings but it does work. However, I prefer user1429080's suggestion of accessing it in the Page_Init so I'm going to run with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the text from the control in the `Page_Init` method. The viewstate is restored to the control tree later in the page processing pipeline. So if you access the text in `Page_Init` and store the value in some suitable place you can get the value from markup (aspx) file.

Comment: Thanks, it's not ideal but it's a clean and simple trick that works

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it with viewstate. but you could create a base page for your site with options to track changes and store the default values when the page is loaded. And a class to do the actual checking.

for example:

Change Tracker:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Class to Track changes in a web page
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class ChangeTracker : IDisposable
    {
        //- MEMBER VARIABLES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Members

        private bool m_ChangesMade = false;
        private Dictionary<string, object> m_OriginalValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        private Dictionary<string, object> m_ChangedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        private List<string> m_ControlsToIgnore = new List<string>();

        #endregion Members

        //- PROPERTIES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Controls to Ignore (ClientID array)
        /// </summary>
        public List<string> ControlsToIgnore
        {
            get { return m_ControlsToIgnore; }
            set { m_ControlsToIgnore = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Dictionay of Changed Values
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, object> ChangedValues
        {
            get { return m_ChangedValues; }
            set { m_ChangedValues = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Dictionay of Original Values
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, object> OriginalValues
        {
            get { return m_OriginalValues; }
            set { m_OriginalValues = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Whether changes have been made to the control collection
        /// </summary>
        public bool ChangesMade
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return m_ChangesMade;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            set { m_ChangesMade = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor (required for serialization)
        /// </summary>
        public ChangeTracker()
        {

        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds all relivant controls recursively to the list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oControl">The control to add</param>
        private void AddControls(Control oControl)
        {
            try
            {
                if (oControl != null)
                {
                    //Check whether the control shoudl be ignored
                    if (!this.ControlsToIgnore.Contains(oControl.ClientID))
                    {
                        //loop recursively
                        foreach (Control aControl in oControl.Controls)
                        {
                            this.AddControls(aControl);
                        }

                        if (oControl is IEditableTextControl)
                        {
                            if (this.OriginalValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                            {
                                this.OriginalValues[oControl.ClientID] = (oControl as IEditableTextControl).Text;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.OriginalValues.Add(oControl.ClientID, (oControl as IEditableTextControl).Text);
                            }
                        }

                        if (oControl is ICheckBoxControl)
                        {
                            if (this.OriginalValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                            {
                                this.OriginalValues[oControl.ClientID] = (oControl as ICheckBoxControl).Checked;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.OriginalValues.Add(oControl.ClientID, (oControl as ICheckBoxControl).Checked);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("oControl");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the controls for changes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oControl">The control to check</param>
        private void CheckControl(Control oControl)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check the control should not be ignored
                if (!this.ControlsToIgnore.Contains(oControl.ClientID))
                {
                    //loop recursively
                    foreach (Control aControl in oControl.Controls)
                    {
                        this.CheckControl(aControl);
                    }

                    if (oControl is IEditableTextControl)
                    {
                        if (this.OriginalValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                        {
                            if (this.OriginalValues[oControl.ClientID].ToString() != (oControl as IEditableTextControl).Text)
                            {
                                if (!this.ChangedValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                                {
                                    this.ChangedValues.Add(oControl.ClientID, (oControl as IEditableTextControl).Text);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.ChangedValues[oControl.ClientID] = (oControl as IEditableTextControl).Text;
                                }
                                this.ChangesMade = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (oControl is ICheckBoxControl)
                    {
                        if (this.OriginalValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                        {
                            if ((bool)this.OriginalValues[oControl.ClientID] != (oControl as ICheckBoxControl).Checked)
                            {
                                if (!this.ChangedValues.ContainsKey(oControl.ClientID))
                                {
                                    this.ChangedValues.Add(oControl.ClientID, (oControl as ICheckBoxControl).Checked);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.ChangedValues[oControl.ClientID] = (oControl as ICheckBoxControl).Checked;
                                }
                                this.ChangesMade = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the default values
        /// </summary>
        ///<param name="oControl">The control to store</param>
        public void StoreDefaultValues(Control oControl)
        {
            try
            {
                //Reset the Original Values collection
                this.OriginalValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                this.ChangesMade = false;

                //Add all relevant controls
                this.AddControls(oControl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the form for changes
        /// </summary>
        ///<param name="oControl">The control to check for changes</param>
        public void CheckForChanges(Control oControl)
        {
            try
            {
                //Instantiate changed values
                this.ChangedValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                //Reset changes made flag
                this.ChangesMade = false;

                //Check controls for changes
                this.CheckControl(oControl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose of the object
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                m_ChangedValues = null;
                m_ControlsToIgnore = null;
                m_OriginalValues = null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion Methods

    }
```

Base Web Page:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds Extra functionality to a web page
/// </summary>
public class WebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Change Tracker
    /// </summary>
    protected ChangeTracker ChangeTracker
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session[String.Format("ChangeTracker{0}", this.ClientID)] == null)
            {
                Session[String.Format("ChangeTracker{0}", this.ClientID)] = new ChangeTracker();
            }

            return Session[String.Format("ChangeTracker{0}", this.ClientID)] as ChangeTracker;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[String.Format("ChangeTracker{0}", this.ClientID)] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets whether changes have been made
    /// </summary>
    protected bool ChangesTracked
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["ChangesTracked"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["ChangesTracked"] = false;
            }

            return (bool)ViewState["ChangesTracked"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ChangesTracked"] = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties


    #region Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the value of the controls after the load completes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">order</param>
    protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnLoadComplete(e);

            //Dont store on postback
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Check whether to track changes
                if (this.ChangesTracked)
                {
                    //Store the default values
                    this.ChangeTracker.StoreDefaultValues(this);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion Events

}
```

Useage (on a save event for example):

```
       //Check for changes
        base.ChangeTracker.CheckForChanges(this);

        //If changes have been made, flag as dirty
        if (base.ChangeTracker.ChangesMade)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
```

As you can see the initial values are stored when the page loaded is complete so they are all available for comparison, or in your case, to reset to original values.